# How enable jabber clients to create chat groups with ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd

How enable jabber clients to create chat groups with ejabberd?
For example, Messages from macOS, create a chat with multiples jabber contacts?

Comment: Just create conference (just enter to any room) and send invites to all contacts.

Comment: Usually it's possible to create by the client software itself, just selecting a list of contacts.